# ODC Installation issue

Tags: open-data-cube

I've tried to install ODC on my local
host but stuck on the UI installation
step.
After running this command:

```
source datacube_env/bin/activate
```

I got "no such file or directory" error.
I also went to localhost:8000 on my
browser, but I got error.

How can I get out
of this issue?

Comment: Could you list the content of your `datacaube_env` directory please?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no such directory. Where I have to find it on my host machine, or in the container?

Comment: Hence the error. You should then provide information on your machine, such as the OS installed (version), what version of the command line environment you use, or any other useful details on your environment, etc. Otherwise people will never be able to guess what's wrong on your computer. ;)

Comment: Sure. I use Ubuntu 20.04 clean installation as vm on Virtualbox with latest updates. Then I followed installation guide from CEOS ODC to install all necessary software and stuck on UI installation step with this error.